# Prevent angular material select list label animation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am currently working with a select list with [angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) but do not require the label animation on selection. I what the label to always appear on top of the select input as it would once you make your selection.

I can get this working with normal text inputs

```
    <md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder">
       <label>Name</label>
       <input type="text"/>
    </md-input-container>
```

[image]

This however does work for [select lists](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) ( link to angular material documentation for select lists ). I cannot get the `what is happening` label to stay fixed on top of the select input.

This is my current code

```
<md-input-container flex="auto" flex="50" class="md-hue-3 md-input-has-placeholder">

 <label>What is happening ?</label>

 <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.alert.effect" class="md-hue-3 ng-not-empty" name="what">
    <md-optgroup label="Select type">
            <md-option ng-repeat="effect in $ctrl.effects">{{effect.name}}</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
  </md-select>
 </md-input-container>
```

The animation is cool and all but i just want a normal input label.

---

This is the hack i have created to make to work, which then involves writing parent selectors in the sass for input active .. its a mess for something so simple

```
<div layout="row">
    <div layout="column" layout-fill>

        <label>What is happening ?</label>

             <md-input-container flex="auto" flex="50" class="md-hue-3">

                  <md-select ng-model="$ctrl.alert.effect" class="md-hue-3" name="what" >
                        <md-optgroup label="Select alert type">
                            <md-option ng-repeat="effect in $ctrl.effects">{{effect.name}}</md-option>
                        </md-optgroup>
                  </md-select>

              </md-input-container>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way to do it (if I got you right)

If you want to disable label animation, just add this to your css:

```
md-input-container.md-input-focused:not([md-no-float]) .md-select-placeholder span:first-child {
   -webkit-transform: none;
   transform: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap **mat-select** to **mat-form-field** with attribute **appearance="standard"** that prevent animation for placeholder and label.
For example:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="standard">
  <mat-select placeholder="set option">
    <mat-option>Option 1</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there in no easy way to do this as this option is not supported. refer to [this bug](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1586) and [this post](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1586#issuecomment-114709461)